# Alert message always showing "successfully updated" even i input wrong using PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a code for updating records and its working fine my only problem is that when i try to messed the code to see if it working and try to submit it the alert message always displaying the "Successfully updated" it should be "updating failed" what ever i try it always displaying this "Successfully updated".can somebody please help me with this?

**here's my code**

**class.user.php**

```
public function  upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE,$username,$password,$province)
{
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE tish_images SET  FILE_NAME=:FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE=:FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE=:FILE_TYPE,username=:username,password=:password,province=:province WHERE id=:id");

$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error ){
if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $errors[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
    continue;
}
$file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
$file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
$file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
$file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
    continue;
}
try{
        $stmt->bindParam( ":id", $id);
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_NAME", $file_name , PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_SIZE", $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_TYPE", $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ":username", $username);
        $stmt->bindParam( ":password", $password);
        $stmt->bindParam( ":province", $province);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;

    $desired_dir="image_uploads";

    if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
    {
        mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);// Create directory if it does not exist
    }
    if(is_file($desired_dir.'/'.$file_name)==false)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
    }
    else
    {    //rename the file if another one exist
        $new_file=$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name.time();
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$new_file) ;               
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
  return false;

}   
}
}
```

**update.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'DB.php';
$username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : '';
$province = isset($_GET['province']) ? $_GET['province'] : '';
$FILE_NAME = isset($_GET['FILE_NAME']) ? $_GET['FILE_NAME'] : '';
$FILE_SIZE = isset($_GET['FILE_SIZE']) ? $_GET['FILE_SIZE'] : '';
$FILE_TYPE = isset($_GET['FILE_TYPE']) ? $_GET['FILE_TYPE'] : '';

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$province = $_POST['province'];

if($crud->upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE,$username,$password,$province))
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!'); </script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!'); </script>";
}

}
if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    extract($crud->getID($id));
    }
?>
```

Comment: You have `return true;` followed by more code that never gets hit. And I assume some of your your `continue`'s should probably be `return false`?

Comment: @Scuzzy what i'm supposed to do?can you help me edit this code please..

Comment: Have you taken code from http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Your checking to see if $crud->upload() is true or false and show the js msgbox in return and based on your code there is nothing that gives a return of true or false. Also try to set your brackets as I have, it makes it a lot more easier to read. Avoid using continue. All that does is continues the script to the next statement.

try this: (place session_start(); on the very top of your main index)

```
public function  upload($id,$FILE_NAME,$FILE_SIZE,$FILE_TYPE,$username,$password,$province)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE tish_images SET  FILE_NAME=:FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE=:FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE=:FILE_TYPE,username=:username,password=:password,province=:province WHERE id=:id");

    $_SESSION['errors'] = array(); //register an empty session array

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error )
    {
        if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        {
            $_SESSION['errors'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
            //continue;
            return FALSE;
        }
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152)
        {
            $_SESSION['errors'] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
            //continue;
            return FALSE;
        }

        try
        {
            $stmt->bindParam( ":id", $id);
            $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_NAME", $file_name , PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_SIZE", $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam( ":FILE_TYPE", $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindParam( ":username", $username);
            $stmt->bindParam( ":password", $password);
            $stmt->bindParam( ":province", $province);
            $stmt->execute();

            $desired_dir="image_uploads";

            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
            {
                mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);// Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_file($desired_dir.'/'.$file_name)==false)
            {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {    //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_file=$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name.time();
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$new_file);  
                return TRUE;             
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
          echo $e->getMessage();
          return false;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `return true;` is still present before `move_uploaded_file` is called

Comment: when the statement return true or return false is used, it exits the script, so just remember that. so anything after that wont be executed.

Comment: @SarmenB. how would i know if the ""insertion failed"  mesgbox is working. because all i see is "updated successfully"?

Comment: you can store the error in a session and after uploading check to see if that session was set and that if it contains any values.

Comment: @SarmenB. can you help me with that.because i'm new in using PDO.i don't know exactly on how to do that?

Comment: @SarmenB. what will happen with that?

Comment: if a error exists the errors results will be stored in a session and you can later , anywhere in your code check to see if there are errors. My method might not be the best way of doing it but its a start. Check here to learn more about sessions http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Do i need to messed my code to see if the "insertion failed" will come out?

Comment: yep, its always best to mess with it to see if it'll break, because if you dont break it, someone will. You can also use the die() function to quickly see if something broke.

Comment: @SarmenB. for example for username i need to make it usernames to see if there's an error?

Comment: add my on gtalk to continue this. sarmenhb@gmail.com